# Passing bytes array from servlet listener to controller

Tags: java, servlets, arrays, listener

I've a servlet context listener, where there is a serial port listener. In this listener I save the bytes from the serial port in this way:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent){
  context = contextEvent.getServletContext();
  serial =  SerialFactory.createInstance();
  serial.open(Serial.DEFAULT_COM_PORT, 19200);
  serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener(){
    @Override
    public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent arg0) {    
    private byte[] serialDataByte;
    serialDataByte = arg0.getData().getBytes();
    context.setAttribute("serialData", serialDataByte);
    seriale.write(serialDataByte); //the echo on serial port show me the right bytes                                
    }           
  });
}
```

on my controller I access to the serial port data by:

```
private byte[] temp;
temp = (byte[]) getServletContext().getAttribute("serialData");
for(int i=0; i<temp.length;i++){
  output.println(Integer.toHexString(temp[i] & 0x00FF));    
}
```

I send to serial port this byte array:

```
aa 7f 40 a 72 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 fe 1a
```

The length is 69. 
Sometimes in my temp array I've only a little part of the original array, sometimes:

```
aa 7f 40 a 72 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

sometimes:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 fe 1a
```

And sometimes the right array of 69 bytes.
How can I pass to my controller the exact data taken from serial port? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If any more data comes in to that port, this code will overwrite what you initially had in the `serialData` context attribute. So only write if the attribute is present, and consider closing the port after the initial `dataRecieved()` call.

```
serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener(){
    @Override
    public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent arg0) {    
        private byte[] serialDataByte;
        if (context.getAttribute("serialData") == null) {
            serialDataByte = arg0.getData().getBytes();
            context.setAttribute("serialData", serialDataByte);
            seriale.write(serialDataByte); // I assume this is only for debugging
                                           // and also supposed to be `serial`
            serial.close();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. In this way how can I save the serial data after the first time if the context attribute is not null? every second a pc send a byte array to this serial port and I need to show in a web page some byte of this array.